# How to translate entire website with Google Translate

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, google-translate

I am currently using the following to translate a web page:

http://translate.google.com/about/intl/en_ALL/tour.html#professional

The problem is, when I put the code snippet generated on the Google site onto my web pages, the user has to choose their language on each page in the website.  Is there any way to do it so that the user only chooses once and then every subsequent page they visit in my website gets automatically translated to their chosen language?

Comment: You can add google translator on your website. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44260037/2339356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this problem only shows up when using Google Chrome.  Other browsers work fine:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-translate-general/browse_thread/thread/4b48a4f997762692

Comment: No even firefox has the same issue.

Comment: every browser has the same issue, even stock Android browsers

Answer (score 0):

The translation widget at the bottom of this page takes the approach of redirecting to google's page translation service which maintains the language but your page has to run inside a google container:

http://www.toronto.ca/

You might be able to listen to change events on the in-page translation widget and store the selected language in LocalStorage so you can automatically reselect it whenever a new page is loaded. However, this approach is pretty hacky since it could easily break whenever google alters the widget.