# Google Website translator translates only single page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, google-translate, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

I'm trying to have a **multi language website in rails.**
So I added the **google translate** from [here](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/)

I added the meta script to my **application.html.erb** so that my whole site is translated.
And the div to my **index page only.**

But it just **translates the index page and not the whole site**. When I open the links in the index page they don't get translated. I don't want to add that div to every page in my site.I read this **stackoverflow sloution** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5507643/1552570) but that is not working for me. Suggest a solution.

I'm also aware of the **Rails I18n library for internationalization** but I guess I need to write all the translations myself manually, which I don't want to do.

Can I18n be automated like Google translator?

Are there any **alternatives** to that which work in fine in Rails?

Comment: For guys still looking answer in this way, You can put the code in your layout so that every page has access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the Google translate plugin code to every page or to which ever page you want to make it work .

Comment: I just want that once the user select the language on homepage the launguage should be set